# Why condition gives error in counting words using python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
import re
file = open("pro.txt").readlines()
for lines in file:
        word= len(re.findall('\Wable#1\W', lines))
        if word in lines:
                sum=sum+1
print sum
```

pro.txt

```
0         6          9     able#1
0         11         34    unable#1
9         12         22    able#1
```

I want to count the number of able#1 in file , if word fine when we use it only in loop but didn't give us the accurate "sum" , and when we put condition on it , it give error of using int instead of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`word` is an integer, not a string. Convert it to a string before the condition.

```
word = str(len(re.findall('\Wable#1\W', lines)))
# or
if str(word) in lines:
    total += 1
```

Also be careful not to use a builtin name as a variable - it could cause problems down the track.

Comment: it also count -able#1 in the text file , how we can remove it

Answer (score 1):

```
open(path).read().count("able#1")
```